# stm (structural topic model) error with content but not prevalence covariate with only some variables

Tags: r, regression

I am running an stm regression and have had no issues with estimateEffect() or stm() without regression. When I run stm with topic and prevalence regressions I get issues 3/5 times.

*Code modified to only include relevant portions [Below works]

```
TB <- as.character(All_Data_cut[,20])

CB <- corpus(TB)
CB <- tokens(CB,
             remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
CB <- tokens_remove(CB, min_nchar = 3)
dfm_B <- dfm(CB)
tfidf_B <- dfm_tfidf(dfm_B)

Dataset_B_complete <- cbind(All_Data_cut[,20], Dataset.1)
colnames(Dataset_B_complete)[1] <- 'Best Responses'
Dataset_B_complete[c(2:7)] <- lapply(Dataset_B_complete[c(2:7)], factor)
Dataset_B_complete <- Dataset_B_complete[complete.cases(Dataset_B_complete),]
Text_to_DFM <- function(Texts){
  Texts <- Texts[,1]
  Corp <- corpus(Texts)
  Toks <- tokens(Corp,
                 remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
  Toks <- tokens_remove(Toks, min_nchar = 3)
  dfm <- dfm(Toks)
  tfidf <- dfm_tfidf(dfm)
  return(dfm)
}
dfm_complete_B <- Text_to_DFM(Dataset_B_complete)
meta_complete_B <- Dataset_B_complete[c(3:7)]
stm_c_B <- convert(dfm_complete_B, to = 'stm', docvars = meta_complete_B)
  # missing: text464, text494
meta_complete_B.1 <- meta_complete_B[-c(464,494),]
STM_B <- stm(stm_c_B$documents, stm_c_B$vocab, 12)
EE_B <- estimateEffect(1:12 ~., STM_B, metadata = meta_complete_B.1)
```

So I ran an regression with stm(). This worked for some variables (two of five):

```
TopCont_gender_B <- stm(stm_c_B$documents, stm_c_B$vocab, K = 12,
                        prevalence = ~ gender,
                        content = ~ gender,
                        data = stm_c_B$meta,
                        seed = 1918)
```

EDIT: I reworked the dfm to remove documents relating to missing covariate values. Same issues arise

```
convert_B <- convert(dfm_complete_B, to = 'stm')
# numbers / texts below CONFIRMED
convert_W <- convert(dfm_complete_W, to = 'stm') #, docvars = meta_W
# numbers / texts below CONFIRMED
convert_O <- convert(dfm_complete_O, to = 'stm')
# numbers / texts below CONFIRMED
convert_O.1 <- convert(dfm_complete_O.1, to = 'stm')
# numbers / texts below CONFIRMED
meta_complete_B <- covar_B[-c(464,494),]
meta_complete_W <- covar_W[-c(895, 920, 1412, 2136, 2858),]
meta_complete_O <- covar_O[-c(379, 680, 691, 989, 1104, 1591, 1960, 2598),]
meta_complete_O.1 <- covar_O.1[-c(170, 1043, 1595, 1755, 2478, 2533, 2857),]

dfm_cut_B <- dfm_complete_B[-c(464,494),]
dfm_cut_W <- dfm_complete_W[-c(895, 920, 1412, 2136, 2858),]
dfm_cut_O <- dfm_complete_O[-c(379, 680, 691, 989, 1104, 1591, 1960, 2598),]
dfm_cut_O.1 <- dfm_complete_O.1[-c(170, 1043, 1595, 1755, 2478, 2533, 2857),]
```

This did not work for the remaining three variables:

```
TopCont_stage_B <- stm(stm_c_B$documents, stm_c_B$vocab, K = 12,
                       prevalence = ~ `Life Stage`,
                       content = ~ `Life Stage`,
                       data = stm_c_B$meta,
                       seed = 1918)
```

I got the error:

Error in stm(stm_c_B$documents, stm_c_B$vocab, K = 12, prevalence = ~`Life Stage`,  :
number of observations in content covariate (0) prevalence covariate (3479) and documents (3479) are not all equal.

All variables are as factors. If they were not, the estimateEffect() should not have worked plus the prevalence covariates are fine (I checked with typeof() as well). Also, the two variables that stm regression worked for one was binary the other had several categorical levels.

I read through the stm paper/documentation. The one thing I did note in the github description (https://rdrr.io/cran/stm/man/stm.html) is that there is some variation on the words used when describing prevalence and topical covariates.

*Unsure how I would send data for reproducible example as is research survey, but any .txt files should work; sorry if this makes the question much more of a hassle to answer.

Any insight is appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the variables that the content stm model worked for and those that it did not were the use of variables with two words for names versus one. In every other situation the use of `variable one` works (not 'variable one') to label variables with more than one term. That is not the case here.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future when they are scratching their head as to why stm is not working for them.